# just downloaded ubuntu on macbook pro and cannot see internet connections available

Tags: wireless, mac, connection

I am just getting started using ubuntu, and am very unfamiliar with the OS and cannot seem to see my wireless connection under network connections, can someone please help me?

Comment: We will need more information to answer your question.  e.g can you see other wireless devices or is it just yours you cant see.

Answer (score 1):

Open up terminal by

```
Shift + Ctrl + T
```

Then type following command to determine which version of MBP you have.

```
  sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
```

You might wanna check here

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro

and here.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1970227

Hope this helps.